# How can i store in an array a sequence of date and time in php-javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, strtotime

I have a Db where are stored in a field a data "startdata", in a second field the time "starttime" and in a second field the frequence: "every 2 days"  or "every 2 hours", and finally a third field with "uptodate" (+4days) and a field with "uptotimetime" (+48hours).

I would like a php page that show me an alert when today is one of the dates in the range startdate-->uptodate or if not that told me how days/hours remaining to the next alert"

I thought at first time to consider only the data fields.
I stored in an array with all the data/time that start from startdate up to the "uptodate" field with a "while" cycle (ie. startdate 07/13 and +4days --> range is :  07/13---> 07/15-->  07/17)

I calculate the enddata:

```
$endg = strtotime ( "+". $dataupto . " days", strtotime ( $row['startdate'] ) ) ;
```

Starting from startdata and ending with enddata and at every step i do the following operation:

```
while (startdata  up to enddata){
    tempdata = startdata + frequence
    arraymonitor[] = tempdata
}
```

In my code is:

```
$endg = strtotime ( "+". $dataupto . " days", strtotime ( $row['startdate'] ) ) ;     
$endg = date ( 'Y/m/d' , $endg ); 
$endgSTR = strtotime($endg);
$tempg = strtotime($row['startdate']); 

while( $tempg < $endgSTR){   

            $arraymonitor[] = strtotime(  date($tempgdate )    );

            $tempg = $tempg + (strtotime ( " +1 days", $tempg  ) ); 


            $arraymonitor[] = $tempg; 
            echo "</br> tempg in while:";
            echo $tempg .  " ";

            echo "</br> tempg in while 2:";
            echo  date ( 'Y/m/d' , $tempg ) .  "<br/>";                     


        }
```

after that i should have an array with all the datas value:
   arraystore = [07/13, 07/15, 07/17]

**but i don't!**

Now i thought to put inside the array the actual data:

```
$arraystore[]= strtotime($oggi);
```

and ordering:

```
rsort($arraytemp); 

print(" </br> ordered array");
print_r($arraytemp);
```

Here, i search and compare today date in arraymonitor with the others date and calculate how many days remaining to the next day:

```
if ( in_array($today, $arraymonitor) ){
    echo "Today u have to monitor";

}else{
    //calculate how many days remaining to the next day


    $arraytemp = $arraymonitor;             
    $arraytemp[]= strtotime($today);   //I add today date in the array      
    rsort($arraytemp); //I ordered the array    
    print(" </br> orderedarray ");
    print_r($arraytemp);
    $keytoday = array_search($oggi, $arraystore);   // I find the data-today key    
    $proxmonitor = $arraystore[$chiaveoggi+1];   // I add "1" that it is the next day, **right**?
```

Here i print the results:

```
    echo " </br> prox day monitor ";
    print(date("Y/m/d",$proxmonitor));  

    $timedayforthenextdata = $proxmonitor - $today;   
    $timedayforthenextdata = (int) $timedayforthenextdata / 60/ 60/ 24;  
    echo "</br> Miss " . $timedayforthenextdata . " days/hours to the next monitoring";
```

I got errors in the "while" cycle because it does not store all the datas!
Why? Where i'm wrong? Any other solution?

My all code:

```
<?php   
$oggi = date("Y/m/d");

foreach($db->query("SELECT startdate, starthour dataupto, hourupto dataevery, hourevery FROM event ") as $row) { 
    #echo $row['annotazione'].' '.$row['Prescrizione']; //etc...



    $monitevery = $row['dataevery'];
    $monitupto = $row['dataupto'];


    $start = $row['startdata'];

    $today = date('Y/m/d');


    $today2 = strtotime($row['startdata']);
    $today2 = strtotime($today);

    echo "start monitor ";
    echo $row['startdate'];
    echo "</br> oggi ";
    echo $today;                    
    $ris = $today2 - $start2;
    $rishour =  (int) ($ris/ 60)/ 60;   // result in hours
    $risdays =  (int) $ris/ 60/ 60/ 24;   // result in hours
    echo "</br> result ";
    echo $risdays;
    //echo gettype($a);
    //echo gettype($b);                 


    $elapseddays = (int) ( strtotime($today) - strtotime($row['startdate'])    )/60/ 60/ 24 ;  //  //today less startdate i find how is passed
    $daysremained = ($row['startdate'] + $monitupto  ) - $today;   // ( startmonit+every = end day )- today =  how may days remains

    echo " <br/>";
    echo "today " .$oggi . "<br/>";
    echo "monitor start " . $row['stardate']. "<br/>";
    echo " days elapsed ";
    echo $elapseddays;   
    if ($elapseddays > 0){ 

        $firstcycleelapsed = strtotime($row['startdate']) + strtotime($row['dataevery']]);  // 20 + 2 = 22


        $dataupto = $row['dataupto'];  
        echo "</br>  dataupto ";
        echo $dataupto;

        $tempgSTR = strtotime($row['startdate']) ; 

        //end day
        $endg = strtotime ( "+". $dataupto . " days", strtotime ( $row['startdate'] ) ) ;     



        $endg = date ( 'Y/m/d' , $endg ); 
        $finegSTR = strtotime($fineg);
        echo " </br> tempg1 " . $row['startdate'] . "<br/>";
        echo " </br> tempg1STR " . $tempgSTR . "<br/>";
        echo " endg1 " . $endg . "<br/>";
        echo " endg1STR " . $endgSTR . "<br/>";


    }

        $arraymonitor = array();

        $tempg = strtotime($row['startdate']);  // i start with the startdate
        echo "</br> after IF dayselapsed>0, before  WHILE:  </br> tempg ";
        echo $tempg . " </br> endg " ;  //tempg e instrotime
        echo $finegSTR;

        $tempgdate = $row['startdate'] ;
        while( $tempg < $finegSTR){   

            $arraymonitor[] = strtotime(  date($tempgdate )    );

            $tempg = $tempg + (strtotime ( " +1 days", $tempg  ) ); 





            $arraymonitor[] = $tempg; 
            echo "</br> tempg in while:";
            echo $tempg .  " ";

            echo "</br> tempg in while 2:";
            echo  date ( 'Y/m/d' , $tempg ) .  "<br/>";                     


        }
        echo "</br>END WHILE:  array date: ";
        print_r($arraymonitor);


        if ( in_array($today, $arraymonitor) ){
            echo "otoday u have to monitor";

        }else{
            //calculate how many days remaining to the next day


            $arraytemp = $arraymonitor;

            $arraytemp[]= strtotime($today);   //i add today date in the array                      
            rsort($arraytemp); //I order the array

            print(" </br> orderedarray ");
            print_r($arraytemp);
            $keytoday = array_search($otoday, $arraytemp);   // i look for the key of today date

            $proxmonitor = $arraytemp[$keytoday+1];   // i add "1" to know what day is the next for showing the alert


            echo " </br> next day of monitor ";
            print(date("Y/m/d",$proxmonitor)); 

            $howmanydaysremain = $proxmonitor - $today;   
            $howmanydaysremain = (int) $howmanydaysremain  / 60/ 60/ 24;  
            echo "</br> reamining " . $howmanydaysremain  . " days  at next monitor";



        }  // end else

    }


}// end for each

?>
```

Comment: What is the JavaScript part of this?

Comment: I did this stuff in php, but maybe if i can solve it also in javascript that's good!

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, change

```
while(){
    ...
    $tempg = $tempg + (strtotime ( " +1 days", $tempg  ) );
    ...
}
```

to

```
while(){
    ...
    $tempg = strtotime ( " +1 days", $tempg  );
    ...
}
```

Then it will calculate "+1 day" correctly and store that date into the array `$arraymonitor`.